# Create new tables using existing table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table A from which I want to query data and create two new tables, one with exactly same schema as the original table, and the other with selected columns from the table A.

When creating a new table with all columns with queried data, I went like this:

```
source_session = working_session
dest_session = sessionmaker(dest_engine)
query = source_session.query(A).filter().sort_by(col).all()
dest_session = dest_session()

## How to create new table with schema of A?

dest_session.add_all(query)  #Bulk-Insert
dest_session.commit()
```

Also, all the tables are in a different schema and not in 'public'.

How should I go about the second part as well? As both the operations will be run concurrently, dropping columns after creation wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance!

(Please let me know if you want to know more about the code)

Comment: Can you not use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtableas.html)?

Comment: For that how should I copy the schema of A or is it not required for `CREATE TABLE AS`?

Comment: Thanks! This worked :) but is there an ORM approach to this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ultimately want to accomplish. If all you want is to copy data then this is the easiest way. If you want to do more things with the copied data then that's a different story.